# Unexpected bluetooth pair prompt between ios9 and ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, ios9, core-bluetooth

I'm building an iOS app that uses Core Bluetooth (BLE) and acts as both, a **peripheral** (in the background) and a **central** when in the foreground, to communicate with anyone else running the same app nearby.

I'm noticing that when the app is on **iOS9** (specifically) and running in **central mode** in the foreground scanning for peripherals, it automatically gets a prompt to pair with the nearby device!

---

**Bluetooth Pairing Request**

"iPhone" would like to pair with your
     iPhone. Confirm that the code
    "701958" is shown on "iPhone".

[Cancel]    [**Pair**]

---

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6sgg.png

This is happening despite the fact that I'm not using encryption in my peripheral's characteristic setup anywhere! It's a simple characteristic with the property value set to "**CBCharacteristicPropertyRead**" and permissions set to "**CBAttributePermissionsReadable**". Also note that the characteristic is setup to be a **static value**, not a dynamic one, and it's meant to be read directly without the need for subscribing for notifications.

**Peripheral (characteristic setup):**

```
CBMutableCharacteristic *characteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc]
                                           initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:uuidStr]
                                           properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
                                           value:myData
                                           permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
```

**Central (trying to connect):**

`[self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];`

The prompt seems to get initiated the moment my iOS9 central initiates a connection request to the discovered iOS8 peripheral device.

Anyone else running into this? This same piece of code has been working great between iOS8<->8, iOS7<->7, iOS8<->7, and even iOS9<->9 (at least as observed in my own testing so far).

Any advice will be very helpful!

Comment: Posted on Apple's dev forums too: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19749 (looks like someone else is having the same issue as well!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received the official response from Apple:

> This has been determined to be caused by a bug in iOS 8. Your best
>   course of action would be to upgrade to iOS 9 on the effected devices,
>   and urge your users to do the same to avoid the issue.

So there you have it. Known issue in iOS 8. Move to iOS 9. :/